# Question about exercise 14.31 in TeXbook

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core, paragraphs, texbook.tex

The following example uses `\signed` macro from page 106 of TeXbook:

```
\tracingonline=1
\tracingparagraphs=1
\def\signed #1 (#2){{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\sl#1\/ \rm(#2)
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}
\hsize 3.0in \noindent
But sometimes an extra line must be added. \signed N. Bourbaki (Paris)
\bye
```

Tracing shows:

```
@firstpass
\tenrm But sometimes an extra line must be added. 
@\penalty via @@0 b=0 p=50 d=2600
@@1: line 1.2 t=2600 -> @@0
 [] \tensl N. 
@ via @@0 b=96 p=0 d=11236
@ via @@1 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@2: line 2.2 t=2700 -> @@1
@@3: line 1.3 t=11236 -> @@0
Bourbaki
@\kern via @@1 b=0 p=0 d=100
@@4: line 2.2 t=2700 -> @@1
 \tenrm (Paris)
@\par via @@1 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@5: line 2.2- t=2700 -> @@1
```

When empty hbox is removed, tracing shows

```
@firstpass
\tenrm But sometimes an extra line must be added. 
@\penalty via @@0 b=0 p=50 d=2600
@@1: line 1.2 t=2600 -> @@0
  \tensl N. 
@ via @@0 b=96 p=0 d=11236
@@2: line 1.3 t=11236 -> @@0
```

and then first pass fails. Why?

Comment: it's some way like if you replace `\signed` with `\hskip2em`.

Comment: @touhami interestingly, if `\signed` is defined as `\def\signed{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50 \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil}`, first pass always succeeds

Comment: OK but this is not what i meant. What i mean is that as far as lines breaking is concerned you can get the same behaviour with `\signed` replaced with `\hskip2em` and with `\hskip2em\hbox{}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glue and penalties are discardable,  so without the box the entire

```
\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em\nobreak\hfil
```

sequence is discardable

If the break happens at the p50 then you would have `N Bourbarki (Paris)` on the second line, so you get badness from stretching two word spaces to fill the line"

But actually it takes the break after N. as that is penalty 0 which in this case is enough to compensate that `Bourbarki (Paris)` has only one word space to stretch so more badness from that but no penalty at the break.

Conversely, the `\hbox{}` is non discardable so if the break is taken at the penalty50, the 2em glue is discarded and the `\hbox{}` ends up at the start of the next line with the glue expanding to flush the text to the right. (This is basically the difference between `\hspace` and `\hspace*` in latex)

Comment: So, without `\hbox{}`, if the  author name is shorter than `\hsize`, break will never be done at any finite penalty?

Comment: I mean, is there any input where break will be done at penalty50?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko yes it's taken in your example, the break happens at the p50 and the 2em space is discarded, so on the second line you get an empty hbox and the hfill

Comment: I'm asking about the case without `\hbox{}`.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko sorry, first answer was basically wrong. I hope this one is better

Comment: I'm unable to come up with an example where break will be done at p50 without `\hbox{}`. Is it impossible that break is done at p50 without `\hbox{}`?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko you need to be able to take that breakpoint without having infintely bad underful box on the second line, the initial hfill is discarded so  you need a long name that fills the line or add some stretch eg `N.\dotfill Bourbaki` will break at the p50, leaving N at the start of the line